# PHP: Evaluate class constant string as code (syntax question)

Tags: php, syntax, constants, eval, traits

Defining a trait I want to write a method which gets the content of a class constant if it exists and is an array, return an empty error otherwise. Just not easy to figure out how to evaluate this class constant call as PHP code.

```
trait FooBar {

    public static function getChildArrayConstant(string $constant): array
    {
        $result = defined(self::class . "::" . $constant) ? ${self::class . "::" . $constant} : [];
        return is_array($result) ? $result : [];
    }

    public function do() {
        var_dump(self::getChildArrayConstant("FOO"); // shall return []
        var_dump(self::getChildArrayConstant("BAR"); // shall return ["foo","bar"]
    }

}
```

The above code **throws an error**. I tried various things including `eval()`, errors always. How would I simple evaluate that correctly to give me the value of the class constant if it exists?

Example of implementing class:

```
class Meow {

    use FooBar;

    public const BAR = ["foo", "bar"];

    public function doMeow() {
        $this->do();
    }
}
```

Comment: "The above code throws an error" Some secret error, I presume?

Comment: @u_mulder: for this case "Warning: Undefined variable $Meow\Meow::BAR"

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question body.

Comment: [`constant(self::class . "::" . $constant)`](https://www.php.net/constant)

Comment: @u_mulder: You won! Did not know there is a function like that, thank you <3

Comment: Whoa, the dupe I answered too.

Comment: Neither did I. So I googled up a similar question on Stack Overflow

Comment: Yes I tried that already, but did not find that information. It is a duplicate, you are right, thanks.